# Sitecore not publishing bucket folders

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, buckets

We have a content folder that has been turned into a bucket to manage the sheer number of items it will contain. The bucket items are published via a workflow and the bucket items are left to be published by the scheduled publish that runs periodically.

For the most part, all works well and fine with regards to the bucket item creation and editing process. But the bucket folders refuse to publish some times. After inspecting the bucket folders, we found that the bucket folders have Version 1 created but when you go to check that version it just lists 'Modified [Not set] by'. This causes the folder items to not be registered in the PublishQueue table and not get published.

The simplest way to fix this is by right-clicking on the folder item, click on Rename and then just click OK on the popup message. This updates the version message to the propery modified by and date values. And also the publish process picks it up.

Has anyone come across this issue or has any tips for us to try?

Comment: what version of Sitecore are you using?

Comment: Sitecore 8 rev. 150223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a know bug.

1) Place the attached Sitecore.Support.413254.dll file to the Webiste\bin folder.

2) Backup the "Sitecore.Buckets.config" file from the Website\App_Config\Inculde folder.

3) In the "Sitecore.Buckets.config" file , change the following processor:

```
  <publish>
   <!-- Extending publish pipeline to always add bucket folders to the queue when a bucketed item is being published  -->
   <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.AddItemsToQueue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.Buckets.Pipelines.Publish.AddBucketFoldersToQueue, Sitecore.Buckets" />
  </publish>
```

with this processor:

```
    <publish>
     <!-- Extending publish pipeline to always add bucket folders to the queue when a bucketed item is being published  -->
     <processor patch:after="processor[@type='Sitecore.Publishing.Pipelines.Publish.AddItemsToQueue, Sitecore.Kernel']" type="Sitecore.Support.Buckets.Pipelines.Publish.AddBucketFoldersToQueue, Sitecore.Support.413254" />
    </publish>
```

Here is the dll:

https://www.dropbox.com/s/thr94mqi8967dab/Sitecore.Support.413254.dll?dl=0